# Setting transparency for all layers in a data frame in ArcMap using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, layers, transparency-opacity, arcgis-10.6

Using ArcMap 10.6, I've tried the following code from a previous post and get an error or it executes but does nothing. Here is the code and error I receive:

**Code**

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument ("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames (mxd, "Layers") [0]
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers (mxd,"", df):
    lyr.transparency = 0
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
mxd.save
del mxd
```

**Error**

> RuntimeError: LayerObject: Set attribute transparency does not exist

Comment: Try testing if the layer supports transparency first http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Layer/00s300000008000000/ if lyr.supports (layer_property): lyr.transparency = 0. Or the *crash and burn* approach try: lyr.transparency = 0 except: pass

Comment: Try printing `lyr.name` before trying to change its transparency to see which layer gives you the error.  Also, please always provide the full error message including its line number.  When refering to any previous post please always include a link to it.

Answer (score 4):

As was mentioned by [@Michael Stimson,](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/15054/michael-stimson) not all layers support transparency.

From the [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm):

> Not all layers support the transparency property (for example, fabric
>   group layers and web service sublayers), so it is good practice to
>   test for this ahead of time using the supports method.

So, your code could look like this:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument ("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames (mxd, "Layers") [0]
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers (mxd,"", df):
    if lyr.supports("TRANSPARENCY"):
        lyr.transparency = 0
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
mxd.save
del mxd
```

One other thing to check is that your data frame is actually called "Layers". If not, the code won't do anything.

It's also important to know that 0 means the layer is not transparent, but 100 means the layer is completely transparent.